# Magento 2 Site css doesnt load or going 404 when clearing admin cache each time

Tags: magento-2.1

When I clear admin Static file cache and Css Javascript cache, the JS and CSS files is not regenerating in pub/static.

Each time I have to deploy using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: is your magento in developer mode ? Recheck by `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: yes it is in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

In developer mode, Magento 2 does not generate static files. It creates symlinks to them from the various modules.

However if you have ran setup:static-content:deploy and have those files in place, it won't update them. Try removing all static files and see if Magento links to them. Make sure you do not remove the .htaccess file form the static folder if you are using apache webserver.

Comment: there is .htaccess file in pub/static. removing doesnt regenerate the files. Can you please help?